# Python: How to rename a set of columns in multiple data frames in certain way

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few data frames and each has multiple columns with names defined in the same way.

Below is an example:

```
person_name birth_dt_1
Bob         1991-01-05 
Abby        1994-09-09
Elsa        1956-08-15
```

I'd like to find a way which can replace the underscore with space in column names and make the first letter of each word upper case. For the numbers in column names, we can keep them as this.

Below is what I want:

```
Person Name Birth Dt 1
Bob         1991-01-05 
Abby        1994-09-09
Elsa        1956-08-15
```

I did not want to use rename function in pandas because I have to specify each column's name, which might be too redundant as the fact that I have multiple data frames, and each has multiple columns.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently doing it? Maybe define a function that can be applied to multiple datasets?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also leverage `re` package in python.

`re.findall` can be used to get the list of potential substrings, which can then be used to join with space.

Example:

```py
import re

def rename_cols(name):
    return " ".join([i.capitalize() for i in re.findall('[a-z0-9]+', name)])

df_clean = df.rename(columns=rename_cols)

Out[1]:
    Person Name Birth Dt 1
0   Bob         1991-01-05
1   Abby        1994-09-09
2   Elsa        1956-08-15
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.title().str.replace('_', ' ')

Out[387]:
  Person Name  Birth Dt 1
0         Bob  1991-01-05
1        Abby  1994-09-09
2        Elsa  1956-08-15
```